# vscode + highlighting eleventy file

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, eleventy

I was wondering what extension I could add to my vscode for `.11ty.js` files. Here is how the file looks with `JS babel`:
[image]

and with `JSTL`:
[image]